# Convert a sorted list of numbers like [1,2,3,4] to a string specifying range like "1-4" in python

Tags: python, list, range

I have a problem in python.

I have a sorted list of numbers like [1,2,3,4,5].
I need to get a string specifying the range like "1-5" if the sorted numbers are in series or continuous.

Thanks
Girish

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What if they aren't in series or continuous?

Comment: Hint: use `min` and `max` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`, you can have the following condition check if it consists of a sequential list of integers before formatting an output with the first and the last item in the list:

```
if l == list(range(l[0], l[-1] + 1)):
    print('{}-{}'.format(l[0], l[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups)

```
import more_itertools

a=[1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,12,13,14,15]

to_range = ["{}-{}".format(groups[0],groups[-1]) for groups in map(list,more_itertools.consecutive_groups(a))]

#['1-5', '8-10', '12-15']
```

If the range has to contain at least 2 elements (i.e., for [1] 1-1 is not allowed) you can add conditions:

```
to_range = ["{}-{}".format(groups[0],groups[-1])  for groups in map(list,more_itertools.consecutive_groups(a)) if groups[0] != groups[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first = my_list[0]
last = my_list[-1]
text = f'{first}-{last}'
```